# Azure New Data Connection stuck on 'Loading...'

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to create a new data connection for my mobile app on the free trial, but it gets stuck on what appears to be a bug in the portal. What can I do?

This is what it looks like.

[image: Portal screenshot]

Comment: Please add some details on _how_ you are trying to establish the connection.

Answer (score 0):

This is believed to be a bug. The team is in the process of fixing this.